# Updating a parent component's state on click on an element in child component

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

```
Parent Component :

const AddTodo = () => {
    const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState(['No active Todos'])


Child Component:

export const Todos = (props) => {
return (
<i class="material-icons close_icon">
clear
</i>
)
```

Now, the question is suppose `todoList` array has some items/todos or even if it's empty. So, how can I call the `setTodoList` function from child(Todos) component to  update the `todoList` array on click of `<i>` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By passing setState as prop you achieve this:

Parent Component :

```
const AddTodo = () => {
    const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState(['No active Todos'])
    return(
        <div>
            {todoList}
            <Todos setTodoList={setTodoList}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Child Component:

```
export const Todos = ({setTodoList}) => {
return (
<i class="material-icons close_icon"
 onClick={()=>setTodoList("")}>
clear
</i>
)
}
```